# Divs won't align to the right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a messaging page, but the divs with the sent messages stack up---there are two in each "row" when there should only be one.

The divs with the class of .message should all float to the right, with only one div per line.

I am using jQuery in my project.

```css
#mydiv{
  width: 80%; 
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 80%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.message{
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  border: 2px solid aqua;
}

#messagebox{
  position: absolute;
  right: 11%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">

</div>
<p/>
<textarea id="messagebox" placeholder="Press enter to send message">
</textarea>
<script>
$('#messagebox').keypress(function(e){
 if(e.which==13){
   e.preventDefault();
    send($(this).val());
    $(this).val("");
  }
});
function send(msg){
 var msgDiv = "<div class='message'>"+msg+"</div>"
 $('#mydiv').append(msgDiv);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: display: inline-block on the boxes you want lined up horizontally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `clear: both` to prevent any floating elements of either side of the `.message` divs (or you can just use `clear: left` to prevent any floating elements to the left of the `.message` divs). See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear).

```css
#mydiv{
  width: 80%; 
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 80%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.message{
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  clear: both;/*prevents floating elements on both sides*/
  border: 2px solid aqua;
}

#messagebox{
  position: absolute;
  right: 11%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">

</div>
<p/>
<textarea id="messagebox" placeholder="Press enter to send message">
</textarea>
<script>
$('#messagebox').keypress(function(e){
  if(e.which==13){
    e.preventDefault();
    send($(this).val());
    $(this).val("");
  }
});
function send(msg){
 var msgDiv = "<div class='message'>"+msg+"</div>"
 $('#mydiv').append(msgDiv);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```